# getting checkbox check and uncheck value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a checkbox below:

```
<%= form_for(:Communication, :html => { :id => "communication_form" }) do |f| %>
<table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <%= f.check_box(:chkbx_Phone, { :id => "cb_Phone", :value => "false" }) %>
            <%= label_tag "Phone" %>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table width="92%">
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <div class="button" style="margin-left:60px;">
                <%= f.submit "Next", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
            </div>
         </td>          
      </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

And I want that If user check on checkbox then it get me value `1` and if user remain uncheck on checkbox then it get me value `0` after click on submit button and below is jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#communication_form").submit(function ( event ) {
      //alert("Hassan");
      var phone_value = $("#cb_Phone").val();
      alert(phone_value);
   });
</script>
```

But it show me only `1` either checkbox is checked or unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in that case, you need to check the checked status of the element

```
var phone_value = $("#cb_Phone").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
```

- [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) - returns true of at least one element in the current set matches the passed selector
- [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a simple code :

```
$('#cb_Phone').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
  // do something
}
 else{ 
 // do something
}
```